# How can I use Pillow (python library) in an R script?

Tags: python, r, python-imaging-library

How can I use Pillow (python library) in an R script ?

In this R Script the use of pillow is necessary for ... , but it throws an error at me !

> ("The Pillow Python package is required to load images")

Help needed ....

```
library(keras)
library(abind)



# get some image
img_path <- system.file('extdata', 'produce.png', package = 'lime')


# load a predefined image classifier
model <- application_vgg16(weights = "imagenet", include_top = TRUE)
```

Downloading data from https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.1/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5
553467904/553467096 [==============================] - 273s 0us/step

```
# create a function that prepare images for the model
img_preprocess <- function(x) {
arrays <- lapply(x, function(path) {
img <- image_load(path, target_size = c(224,224))   # <-- this is what generates the error !
x <- image_to_array(img)
x <- array_reshape(x, c(1, dim(x)))
x <- imagenet_preprocess_input(x)
})
do.call(abind, c(arrays, list(along = 1)))
}




# Create an explainer (lime recognise the path as an image)
explainer <- lime(img_path, as_classifier(model, unlist(labels)), img_preprocess)




# Explain the model (can take a long time depending on your system)
explanation <- lime::explain(img_path, explainer, n_labels = 2, n_features = 10, n_superpixels = 70)
```

> Error in `image_load(path, target_size = c(224, 224))` : The Pillow
>   Python package is required to load images

But ho can I use the Python Pillow library in this R script ?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: You possibly do not need to explicitly use Pillow since `image_load` calls it. In fact [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/keras/versions/2.1.3/topics/image_load) suggests PIL version x.x. Do you have Python installed (likely with `keras`)? And did you `pip` install Pillow?

Comment: It seems that pip install Pillow was enough to remove the error! I need to check if there are any other problems though. Thank you.